# gcloud 'no such file or directory'

Tags: gcloud

On Ubuntu 20.04, gcloud installed with `snap install google-cloud-sdk --classic`...

Today it no longer works. Yesterday there was an auto update.

```
$ kubectl get all
Unable to connect to the server: error executing access token command "/snap/google-cloud-sdk/188/bin/gcloud config config-helper --format=json": err=fork/exec /snap/google-cloud-sdk/188/bin/gcloud: no such file or directory output= stderr=
```

Version 188 it is referencing is gone, and it is now at 190. (Version 189 is also present.)

I've uninstalled and deleted the .config/gcloud, and reinstalled, but still have the same error.

Any tips on where to look for that stale path?

Comment: I suspect it is to be found in your kubectl config file (on Linux: `${HOME}/.kube/config` or possibly as the value of `${KUBECONFIG}`. For GKE clusters, the relevant `user`, `auth-provider`, `config` will include something similar to `cmd-path: /.../google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud` and I think that's what you'll want to edit.

Comment: Exactly right, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll post as the answer for posterity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that gcloud stores the absolete reference to the gcloud binary to ~/.kube/config. The solution is to replace `/snap/google-cloud-sdk/.*/gcloud` -> `/snap/bin/gcloud` in `~/.kube/config`.

Example of accomplishing this with `perl` on the command line:

```
perl -i -p -e 's/\/snap\/google-cloud-(sdk|cli)\/.*?\/gcloud/\/snap\/bin\/gcloud/' ~/.kube/config
```

Comment: In my case, it was /snap/google-cloud-cli/23/bin/gcloud, that I've needed to change to /snap/bin/gcloud (google-cloud-cli instead of google-cloud-sdk)